# magento Enable 'free shipping' only when certain discount code used

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

we have a discount code set-up for friends. When they use it they get 10% off. In reality many friends logically live nearby and hence ask me: why cant I also pickup the items this weekend? We do however in general not support pickup.

What we would like is the following. When the "friend discount code" is used - only known to friends - the option 'free shipping/pickup' should become available. Only in this case. (ad. We dont want to offer free shipping persé. Some friends do live far away and get it per post, but we want them to have the option to choose)

Any tips or ideas on how this could be accomplished?

[UPDATE]
I am thinking 2 solutions.

1. Create a second discount code that enables free shipping (and you also only tell your friends to use when they want to pickup)
2. Little more difficult - but does what we want: Edit files in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method
   (are these the right ones?)
   a. in loop addding shipping methods add free shipping
   b. but only if variable get couponcode is value XYZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a customer group for special customers
- Assign those special customers to this group
- Create a shopping cart price rules for %10 discount
- Select the customer group that we created above from "customer groups" section
- Apply necessary settings for the rule ( coupon code etc.. )

also, take the following references :

- [What are Shopping Cart Price Rules and how do I use them?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [How to Setup Simple Customer Specific Discount Pricing](http://www.beperpetual.com/2009/04/how-to-setup-customer-pricing-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to 
create a website on your store for friends only.
Forbid guest buy there.
Forbid open registration.
(you can forbid browsing without login)
Configure settings for website, you need.